# Regex Expression to Append to Front or End of a String with an Incremented Variable

Tags: regex, increment

Is it possible with Regex to do this ?

I need to append a string to the front of a set of existing strings with an incremented variable for each line...

so for example...

File abc

File def

File ghi

becomes...

(Audio 01) file abc

(Audio 02) file def

(Audio 03) file ghi

or the same with the addition appended as a suffix at the end of the
original string ?

Please tell me yes and show me how...  :)

Thanks in advance...

~by

Comment: Is regex a requirement? Because you are not using the good tool for the job.

Comment: Oh and to Simon Belanger's response/question, yes regex is my only option in the application I am using (MP3Tag)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the way to go about doing that. Regular expressions are not meant for dealing with phrases that require context to be changed. The number that follows the word audio is dependent on the number of files before this one, which is context.

A better and simpler solution would be to write a script that counts the occurences and replaces it appropriately. Scripts are much better and simpler than regex in this case.